Array out of bounds exception in a recursive program for calculating determinant
I am making a recursive program in java that calculates determinant of a matrix. I have made a base case but still am getting a array out of bounds exception. I am trying to wrap my head around that problem but still not able to figure out the problematic line;
This is the code:
import java.util.*;

public class linear_equation{
    public static float determinant(float[][] a) {
        int len = a.length;
        if (a.length == 1) {
            return (a[0][0]);
        } else {
            float ans = 0;
            float s[][] = new float[len - 1][len - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= len; j++) {
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        s[i][j] = a[i][j];
                    }
                    ans += a[0][j] * determinant(s) * (Math.pow(-1, i));
                }
            }
            return (ans);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter length of the determinant");
        int len = sc.nextInt();
        float a[][] = new float[len][len];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                a[i][j] = sc.nextFloat();
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Determinant is: " + determinant(a));
    }
}

And this is the error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at linear_equation.determinant(linear_equation.java:18)
        at linear_equation.main(linear_equation.java:40)

I made a similar program in python with almost same base case and that is working fine
if len(a)==1:
        return a[0][0]
    ans=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        s = [j[:i] + j[i+1:] for j in a[1:]]
        ans += a[0][i] * determinant(s) * ((-1)**i)
    return ans


Hello Arnsv, change for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) { and for (int j = 0; j <= len; j++) { for for (int i = 0; i <= s.length; i++) { and for (int j = 0; j <= s.length; j++) {*.

You've written it that way. Your java code does not match your python code.
Let's say your input has length value of 5.
Then, you declare a new array named s whose lengths are 4 (len-1). That means s[0][0] all the way through s[3][3] are valid. [3][4] would not be valid; index number 4 is for the 5th element (because index number 0 is for the first element - java, like most languages and like python, is 0-indexed).
You then loop through 0 up to and including the length, so from 0 to 5.
You try to set s[5][5] in that loop. That doesn't work. s[4][4] wouldn't even work. You either meant to write for (int j = 0 ; j < len-1; j++) instead of what you have (which is j <= len - that's off by 2), or, you meant to write float s[][] = new float[len+1][len+1] instead the [len-1][len-1] that you have. Or, your entire algorithm is broken, but that's beyond the scope of what you asked.

Your Java code does not do what the working Python code does. There are these issues:

You have declared (correctly) s as a smaller matrix than a, but then try to populate it as if it is larger than a, as you allow i and j to become equal to len-1 (that's an index that is out of range for s), and even equal to len (that's an index that is out of range for both s and a)

Related, but you never initialise the first row and column of s. Instead, in the first row of s you should store the values of the second row of a, ...etc.

determinant is called within a nested loop, while it should be called (only) in a single loop that iterates over the columns.

Related, but in the formula a[0][j] * determinant(s) * (Math.pow(-1, i)) you use both i and j, while in the Python code you only use one index (i).

You create and populate s only once, while the Python code does this several times. And also, you call determinant recursively with s even before s has been completely populated.


This list should be enough to realise this is quite different from the intended algorithm.
Correction
Here is a correction:
    public static float determinant(float[][] a) {
        int len = a.length;
        if (len == 1) {
            return (a[0][0]);
        } else {
            // Create a copy of A without row 0 and column 0 into S 
            float s[][] = new float[len - 1][len - 1];
            for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < len; j++) {
                    // The data gets stored in a shifted way
                    s[j - 1][i - 1] = a[j][i];
                }
            }
            float ans = a[0][0] * determinant(s);
            for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                // Replace a column in S with the previously excluded one 
                for (int j = 1; j < len; j++) {
                    s[j - 1][i - 1] = a[j][i - 1];
                }
                // So now, in S, A's row 0 and column i are excluded
                ans += a[0][i] * determinant(s) * Math.pow(-1, i);
            }
            return ans;
        }
    }

